# iphone ui view components

Tags: iphone

anyone can give me an idea of what are the ios ui components used in the picture below?

especially for the 2nd picture, the lower part is a grouped table (correct me if i'm wrong), what about the upper part?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**List Controller:**

- UINavigationController with UITableView as RootViewController and a UITabBar

**Detail Controller:**

- UITableViewController with 3 Sections (UITableViewStyleGrouped).
- The Picture above uses:

  - (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section

which returns a UIView to use as the section header for the first section. This UIView has an UIImageView and a few UILabels.

**Photo Controller:**

- UIViewController with a UIImageView placed on top.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like a custom view - either composed (self-painted) in drawRect: or composed of an image and a couple of labels. I suppose it's the latter (because of the "..." to shorten the text).

Answer (score 1):

You can do it easily using IB.

You drag a uiview in the topview and a tableview in the bottom view. Then, inside the top UIView, you can drag whatever you want:)

Answer (score 0):

I would say the detailcontroller consists of a static UIView on the top and an TableView below